# When does PyTorch automatically cast Tensor dtype?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

When does PyTorch automatically cast Tensor dtype? Why does it sometimes do it automatically and other times throws and error?

For example this automatically casts `c` to be a float:

```
a = torch.tensor(5)    
b = torch.tensor(5.)
c = a*b 

a.dtype
>>> torch.int64

b.dtype
>>> torch.float32

c.dtype
>>> torch.float32
```

But this throws an error:

```
a = torch.ones(2, dtype=torch.float)   
b = torch.ones(2, dtype=torch.long)    
c = torch.matmul(a,b)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-128-fbff7a713ff0>", line 1, in <module>
    torch.matmul(a,b)

RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Long for argument #2 'tensor'
```

I'm confused since Numpy seems to automatically cast all arrays as necessary e.g.

```
a = np.ones(2, dtype=np.long)
b = np.ones(2, dtype=np.float)

np.matmul(a,b)
>>> 2.0

a*b
>>> array([1., 1.])
```

Comment: It throws the error in the first case (also) for me. I'm using PyTorch 0.4.1

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the PyTorch team is working on those types of problems, see [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6196). It seems like some basic upcasting is already implemented in 1.0.0 as per your example (probably for the overloaded operators, tried some others like '//' or addition and they work fine), did not find any proof of this though (like github issue or info in documentation). If someone finds it (implicit casting of `torch.Tensor` for various operations), please post a comment or another answer.

[This issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9515) is a proposal on type promotion, as you can see all of those are still open.